# Rest UserName/Password authentication not working!

Tags: apex

I am trying to get aouth token from using the username and password authentication for Salesforce rest api.

I am using this url: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

I am using this Header:

```
grant_type: password
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id: 3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp7vvFtoM5KvlxGGeHkTNHMBRocXHDKgrY.**********************
client_secret: 77228**********
username: ******@****.com
password: ********ESbfkvMHuULtcEROf6CNiMRZ
```

I am also giving the accesstoken in the password.
but I am always getting this:

```
error_description: "grant type not supported"
error: "unsupported_grant_type"
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your code ?the first step should be to obtain access token

Comment: i am using a tool for rest post callouts called: Advance rest client(chrome plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using this Endpoint https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Change your Endpoint to https://[Your salesforce instance].salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Example :https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Comment: I did that but same result!!

Comment: I got the Result in POSTMAN Client ..am not able to understand why u r not getting  it

Comment: even tried it in POSTMAN client same result, what Header values are you using???

Comment: client_id ,client_secret,grant_type,username,password

Comment: what did u entered in u r Callback URL ?

Comment: it has my website address "callbackurl".. as "www.mysite.com"

Comment: Mention this as CallBack uRl https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Comment: You mean inside salesforce Remote Access??? I did that but same result..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12229/discussion-between-vineeth-and-user614946)